# Nested loops pr

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I'm new in the area of programming in Python and programming in general so I have a problem creating nested loops.

I want to create 3 arrays: `X1`, `delta_X` & `X2`

`Delta_X` array consist of random numbers which I create using `numpy.random.uniform` setting required boundaries.

`X1[0]` is for example value 5, and

```
X1[1]=X2[0] 
X1[2]=X2[1]
……
X1[n]=X2[n-1]
```

And

```
X2[i]=X1[i]+delta_X[i]
```

Please, can you explain me how to create mentioned `X1` and `X2` array?

Comment: [So what is your approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that `X1` and `X2` depend on each other, so you can't create one without having the other.

The only solution I see is to build them together:

lets say you already have:

```
delta_X = [1,2,3,4,5]
X1 = [5]
X2 = []
```

What you need to do is to iterate over `delta_X` and `append` values to `X2` and `X1`:

```
for i,d in enumerate(delta_X):
    X2.append(X1[i]+delta_X[i])
    X1.append(X2[i])
```

For this example, `X1` and `X2` will be:

```
X1 = [5, 6, 8, 11, 15, 20] 
X2 = [6, 8, 11, 15, 20]
```

Comment: Still getting this error: TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'


C/P code:

def tlakovi_i_temperature(self):
    self.delta_P=np.random.uniform(low=-10,high=-1,size=len(self.korak))
    self.P1=self.dinamicki_tlak_bar
    self.P2=[]
    for i, d in enumerate(self.delta_P):
        self.P2.append(self.P1[i] + self.delta_P[i])
        self.P1.append(self.P2[i])
    return self.delta_P, self.P1, self.P2

Comment: probably because you defined `X1= 5` instead of `X1 = [5]` or `delta_X` is not defined correctly. Add your code to the question so we can help you

Comment: I do not know how to edit a comment so it would look as appropriate as your answer... Sorry

Comment: Edit your question, this is more valuable than editing a comment. Most people will miss it and you can't format your code properly in comments.

Comment: AndreyF, you were right! Now I transformed it to x1=[5] and it is working. Many thanks!!!!!

Comment: @python_beginner np, you can accept the answer if it was helpful

Comment: Now I have problem finding averages between P1 and P2 since P1 has 11 shape and P2 10 shape. Do you have an idea how to solve that?

Comment: If you just want to calculate the mean of a list you can use `sum` and `len` to calculate it. Otherwise you should explain what you want in another question

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach (I am not sure about how numpy array elements are accessed)

```
X1 = [5]          # Since, X1[0] = 5
X2 = []

for i in range(len(delta_X)):
    X2.append(X1[i] + delta_X[i])
    X1.append(X2[-1])
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'     I changed X with P and code is:     def tlakovi_i_temperature(self):
        self.delta_P=np.random.uniform(low=-10,high=-1,size=len(self.korak))
        P2=[]
        P1=[]
        P1=self.dinamicki_tlak_bar
        for i in range (len(self.korak)):
            P2.append(P1[i] + delta_P[i])
            P1.append(P2[i - 1])
        return self.delta_P, self.P1, self.P2

Comment: This _might_ work if delta_X is a list and not a numpy array.